# Loading different control in different row of Telerik Grid in EDIT mode

Tags: asp.net, sql, telerik

I want to load different controls like DROPDOWN,RADIO in single column in Telerik Rad Grid's edit mode.

Means in every row, i want to pass some value from database like

---

### id        |   control|

1         | dropdown
2         | radio
3         | checkbox

now when i pass 1 in column , telerik grid should load dropdownbox in edit mode.
in another row if i pass 2 than in same column but in that perticular row it should load radio button in edit mode.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set **AutoGenerateColumns="False"** and then create your custom "RadGridTemplateColumn"'s in your ascx-file.
In each TemplateColumn you can define "HeaderTemplate", "ItemTemplate", "EditTemplate". The EditTemplate will be shown if you are in edit mode.
In this you can show your controls.

Iam not sure what you exactly mean but I think you wanna show a dropdownlist in the Row 0 of your grid and in the next item (Row 1) you wanna show at the same position a radiobuttonlist right?

You can achive this by using the Event "OnItemDataBound".

```
if (e.Item is GridEditFormItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
{
}
```

use this to be sure that you are in the editmode.
There you can for example hide some controls or maybe create them dynamically and add them to the page.
If you wanna create new controls dynamically I would suggest you to place a asp:PlaceHolder at the specific position in your ascx-file.

hope I understood you right.

best regards, noone.